# NetworkStream.Read download progress. In similar to WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged

Tags: c#, http, webclient, bandwidth, networkstream

I want to know current download progress when im using NetworkStream.Read. Is it even possible? Do i have to use webclient?

I dont want to use webclient because it seems(im not 100% sure)

1. i have to create webserver
2. i have to create file (instead of memory stream data).
3. i cannot properly measure transfer speed of gigabit networks, due to http protocol limitation.

or, i should use webclient?

FYI, Im building bandwidth estimation tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem?

1. Get the current time
2. Invoke ´stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` in a loop until you get enough bytes to calculate a proper rate
3. Take end time
4. Divide the received byte length with number of seconds it took download them.
5. Result = bytes/s

Comment: There is process overhead using stream.Read multiple times vs one time. The best way is to use stream.Read once by providing buffer with similar size with expected receive data. The problem with your method is that the result is not accurate and fluctuate with different size. The results is even different if using different pc. The only thing that is similar across all testing platform is the amount of data transferred obtain using IPv4InterfaceStatistics.BytesReceived. The problem with IPv4InterfaceStatistics.BytesReceived is that it captures all data transferred through the nic. Continue..

Comment: I want the amount of data transfered FROM my application, not all data on the same nic. FYI, my ultimate goal is to measure maximum channel capacity, not good data transfered. Since the bandwidth fluctuate unpredictably, i cannot use the simple method that you provide. FYI, i perform all these measurement using network emulator under perfect network condition(as possible).

Comment: Since stackoverflow comment cannot support multiple line breaks, i cannot post the results here. What im trying to say is that, these results clearly shows the difference in fluctuation across different testing configurations. And since its unpredictable, i cannot deduce any conclusion out of it. What i can say is that, one cannot use the simple method to capture channel capacity. One can use IPv4InterfaceStatistics.BytesReceived to measure channel capacity, as long as the channel is not used by any other connection. Hope this clears up confusion.

Comment: ehh. Overhead? The overhead is so small that it's negligible unless you download very small buffers.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should only do one loop. You need to do multiple iterations, keeping the bytes/s for each iteration. Then calculate an average.

Comment: @jgauffin. you are not answering my questions. how do you know that  the overhead is so small that it's negligible? from my lab test results, the difference can be as low as 9% up to 22% for channel capacity 1mbps to 20mbps. for each mbps, i perform 100 test. to eliminate spikes, i use median of data rate. different pc conf yield diff maximum results but same minimum results(results = diff between channel capacity and data transfer rate)(data transfer rate is total data received/total time).

Comment: my measurement procedure is as accurate as can be(i work at a national telco. i have access to very expensive measurement equiepment.)ive been dealing with bandwidth estimation problem for months, so please, cut me some slack and do answer my questions.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid your questions or say that your measurement procedure is inaccurate. Can you update your question (not a new comment) with the code that you use to check the bandwidth? Press the 'edit' link under it.